# In the calculation of sunrise, where do the magic numbers come from?

Tags: astronomy, time, sun

In this [question about how to calculate sunrise](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26617/how-to-determine-day-night-based-on-latitude-longitude-and-a-date-time), 
there is a link to a page that describes a [algorithm to calculate sunrise sunset](http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm).

But when I start to follow the instructions I find that there is a lot of magical constants in that instruction and it is hard to understand what is going on.

For example this part:

> 3. Calculate the Sun's mean anomaly
>      $$M = 0.9856 t - 3.289$$

Where did he find $0.9856$ and $3.289$?

And in the next part

> 4. Calculate the Sun's true longitude 
>         $$ L = M +  1.916 \sin(M) +  0.020 \sin(2   M) + 282.634$$
>      Note: $L$ potentially needs to be adjusted into the range $[0,360)$ by adding/subtracting $360$.

Where did he find $1.916$, $0.020$ and $282.634$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mean anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) relates position and time of an orbiting body. It is zero at the perihelion and increases with time. Its formula is: $M=M_0+nt$.

So, in this case $M_0=-3.289°$ is the mean anomaly when the measurement was made. $n=0.9856$ is the [mean motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_motion), which is $2\pi$ divided by the duration of the full orbit.

More information [here](http://stjarnhimlen.se/comp/ppcomp.html).